# What renders fast? fillRect() vs moveTo(), lineTo(), stroke()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a legacy code where timeline for video is rendering using Canvas (as i understood, it's faster than DOM rendering).
So, the author wrote a code with `fillRect()` method, but later he rewrote it to combination `moveTo(), lineTo(), stroke()`.

The timeline looks like rectangle 8*1000px and can consist hundreds rectangles.
I can't ask him why he did this changes and I have opinion that using `fillRect()` is better.

Is `fillRect()` renders as fast as lines (with fill inside)?

Comment: Why not try it yourself? It's pretty easy to build a benchmark for that.

Comment: `fillRect()` does not do what `stroke()` does, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method will almost always be faster.

Until it actually has to **paint** something, all the context API does is simple arithmetic, all on the CPU and this is pretty fast.
What takes a long time is all the complex painting part + compositing.
Generally, to make this slow part faster, browsers will move that part to the GPU. But it still has to move all the data from the RAM to the GPU memory, and this takes some time.

So building a complex shape all on the CPU using the path manipulations methods and calling `fill()` or `stroke()` only once will definitively be faster than creating the same complex path while calling these `fill()` and `stroke()` several times like `fillRect` or `strokeRect` are bound to do.

```js
const rects = Array.from({ length: 300 }, (_) => ({
  x: Math.random() * 1000,
  y: Math.random() * 1000,
  s: Math.random() * 200 + 50
}));
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Benchmark.js playground borrowed from 
// https://jsfiddle.net/533hc71h/

var test1_name = 'fillRect';
function test1() {
  rects.forEach(({ x, y, s }) => ctx.fillRect(x, y, s, s));
}
var test2_name = 'path + fill()';
function test2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  rects.forEach(({ x, y, s }) => ctx.rect(x, y, s, s));
  ctx.fill();
}

function teardown() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

var cycleResults = document.getElementById('cycleResults');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// BENCHMARK ====================
btn.onclick = function runTests() {

  btn.setAttribute('disable', true);
  cycleResults.innerHTML = '';
  result.textContent = 'Tests running...';

  var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

  // add tests
  suite
    .add(test1_name || 'test1', test1)
    .add(test2_name || 'test2', test2)
    // add listeners
    .on('cycle', function(event) {
      var result = document.createElement('li');
      result.textContent = String(event.target);

      document.getElementById('cycleResults')
        .appendChild(result);
    })
    .on('complete', function() {
      result.textContent = 'Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name');
      btn.setAttribute('disable', false);
      teardown();
      test2();
    })
    .run({
      async: true
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/1.0.0/benchmark.min.js"></script>

<ul id='cycleResults'>

</ul>
<div id="result">

</div>
<br>
<button id="btn">
Run Tests
</button><br>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```